# Haskell different Implementation based on Type Class

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism

I have a dataType called signal which can be Double or Integer I have implemented it as follows.

```hs
data Signal a = Signal
  { name :: String
  , value :: a
  }
```

Now I want to provide two different implementation based of Signal in my method

```hs
   generateSignal :: Signal a -> a
   generateSignal Signal(name, value :: Bool) = value
   generateSignal Signal(name, value :: Double) = value + 1.0
```

Is there a method to achieve this ?

**Edit:**
More Context:
Basically I am writing a library in haskell were for stock trading. I was planning to create a Signal type similar to this and then eventually writes simple rules [build a UI in future].

So some example of Signals would be

```
shouldBuyStock :: Signal Bool
shouldBuyStock = Signal {
name: "shouldBuyClassifier",
value:  shouldBuyClassifier
--- This is a ML Model will tells should I buy any given stock
}

expectedConfidenceToRise :: Signal Bool
expectedConfidenceToRise = Signal {
name: "expectedConfidenceToRise",
value: expectedConfidenceToRise
--- This is a ML Model will tells should I buy any given stock and gives a numerical model
}
```

Eventually I want to make a UI which will allow me to write rules like

```
[("shouldBuyClassifier", True), ("expectedConfidenceToRise", 0.9)] = Buy
```

Given the solution below I would create a type

```
class comparableSignal where
  matches :: Signal a -> Signal b -> Bool

instance comparableSignal Bool Bool where
  generateSignal (Signal _ value1) (Signal _ value2) = value1 == value2

instance comparableSignal Bool Double where
  generateSignal (Signal _ value1) (Signal _ value2) = False

instance comparableSignal Double Double where
  generateSignal (Signal _ value1) (Signal _ value2) = value1 == value2

instance comparableSignal Double Bool where
  generateSignal (Signal _ value1) (Signal _ value2) = False
```

I have already accepted the answer as the answer to original question.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with typeclasses:

```
data Signal a = Signal
  { name :: String
  , value :: a
  }

class GenerateSignal a where
  generateSignal :: Signal a -> a

instance GenerateSignal Bool where
  generateSignal (Signal _ value) = value

instance GenerateSignal Double where
  generateSignal (Signal _ value) = value + 1.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. I am a noob in haskell is this considered a good use of Typeclasses.

Comment: You haven't provided enough context/details of your actual problem for me to be able to answer that.

Comment: Added more context and the actual usage in the after editing the question.